# What is the Alternative to a Selenium Bot Written in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, bots, puppeteer

I've finished building a basic web scraping bot that performs tasks on my desired website. After finishing, I've realised that selenium is very slow for parsing through web data, and that larger tasks can take minutes or longer to execute. Essentially my basic bot searches on a website then parses through the different articles and logs the results. My bot is written in Python 3 and it imports the selenium webdriver. The extent of the tasks involves clicking a search bar, typing in it, entering, then finding the top articles and logging them. I was wanting to advance this to engaging with articles and communicating with article authors, with 5-10 contacted per task. I've done it on theverge.com but this was only a test site, not the real deal.

I have heard about sending a GET request to a URL and adding a search query to the URL then parsing a response. However, i'm not sure how to do this, any references for this would be great to start me in the right direction. I'm also considering using Node for the heavy JavaScript sites, with puppeteer for loading and parsing dynamic web pages.

Any tips or suggestions that will point me in the right direction is appreciated

Except of my code for reference

```
driver.get("https://www.theverge.com/")
print(driver.title)

search_button = driver.find_elements_by_id("icon-search")

search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search.send_keys("facebook")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Facebook’s old web design will disappear in September")))
    element.click()

except:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: search module `requests` or `urllib` to get HTML from server and later send form data, and module `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to parse HTML and search data in HTML. But this doesn't run JavaScript and if you have pages with JavaScript then you still may need `Selenium` but you can try to run without displayin window - in `headless` mode.

Answer (score 2):

Use **urllib/urllib3** (for Python 2 or 3 respectively), **requests** with **BeautifulSoup4**.
You are doing too much work to get the search you need. This will be enough to get the first link.

```
import requests, urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.theverge.com/search?q=facebook"

session = requests.Session()
url = session.get(link).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')
titles = soup.select('.c-entry-box--compact__title > a')

for title in titles:
    if title.has_attr('href'):
        print(title.attrs['href'])
        break
```

Use [Requests-HTML](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) which can be used for Javascript websites.

Comment: Request-HTML full javascript support, thanks for that !